# Styling <BR> to have margins like <P>

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I want to style my `<BR>` elements to have margins more like `<P>` elements. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like but except for postal addresses, you shouldn't have many `br` elements in your code, at least not 2+ of them in a row. If different `p` need different margins then use classes or ids to style them and check if it's really needed: your design shouldn't have different margins (not too many)

Comment: @FelipeAls: There are portals/systems, e.g. Wikidot, where the text you enter into articles converts newlines to `<br>` as the default separator, and takes a lot of jumping through hoops if you want `<p>` instead. Styling <br> to act as paragraph breaks can be done on theme side, user-editable. Replacing that with <p> would take either convincing portal owners to modify the engine, or some awful javascript to convert <br> to <p> on the fly.

Comment: @SF I expect such crappy editors to exist but markup still shouldn't be done like that. My comment 3 years ago was to describe good practice, in case something could be done to these `<br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line-height`. You have to have two `<br />`, first to break line and second to add range between lines.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
br {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Works only on Gecko up to version 2 (Firefox 4).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any style to almost any element using CSS.

Default margin for P element is 1em 0; So, your CSS code should look like this:

```
br { 
    margin: 1em 0; 
}
```

If you need to see default or current style properties for any element, you can use Firefox with Firebug or Chome/Safari/Opera Developer Tools.

Comment: it doesn't works, even i set the display:block for the br element.

Comment: Works only on Gecko up to version 2 (Firefox 4).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why boogyman's answer has -2, but that's correct. To do what you're asking, try

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

That will break the line and still give you the margin.